# can not create queue for QManager

Tags: ibm-mq

I encountered a really wired problem. I have successfully install `Websphere MQ` on my windows machine and want to create `QManager` and Queue to connect to a remote `Qmanager` server. I have already created a QManager as you can see in the picture below. However, when I tried to create a queue for this `QManager`, I could not find any expand button as the IBM tutorial mentioned. 
I have already tried to create a queue with MQSC but when I run `runmqsc` in the command prompt with administrator user, it shows `AMQ8135: Not Authorized` error!

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your error logs (AMQERR01.LOG) for an explanation of why AMQ8135 was returned to the client - for security reasons clients aren't given more information and so you have to go to the logs to get the detail.

I suspect the user you're running MQ Explorer and runmqsc as isn't in the 'mqm' group, or is otherwise not authorised to connect to the queue manager.

Comment: The longer answer would also advise that rather than putting the MQ service account in the Administrators group, it is best to properly authorize the ID *inside* of MQ so the QMgr *never* has root on the Windows host.  That said, MQ sees only the first 12 chars of the user name so tries to authorize "Administrato" when Administrator tries to connect.  This often leads to auths errors which are counterintuitive since the ID use appears to have admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

Run your IBM MQ Explorer as administrator and it will solve most of the issues.

Comment: Whilst this approach will work because the administrator user will probably have the needed MQ authorities, you're circumventing a lot of security doing things this way. I advise that you instead understand the authorisation failure for your user ID and resolve that instead.

Comment: Points for resolving the security without disabling it in the process.